# Select text in input field of AngularUI modal when it opens

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [AngularUI modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) in my app. Modal contains input field that is pre populated with some value. 
**Request:** When modal opens, text in that input field should be selected.

I have made directive for selected text input and furthest I got is selecting all text when input is clicked according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995884/select-text-on-input-focus-in-angular-js) answer, which is fine but I need that functionality when modal is opened.

I have seen in [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999501/angularui-bootstrap-modal-open-event) that modal instance has "opened" promise but inside that block I can't access the input.

Modal dialog:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({

templateUrl: 'app/main/templates/dialogs/share-dialog.tpl.html',
controller: function ModalCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, item) {

    $scope.ok = function () {

        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

},
resolve: {
    item: function () {
        return item;
    }
}
});
```

Template part with select directive:

```
<input ng-model="shareLink" type="text" class="form-control" id="share" selected-text >
```

Selected text directive:

```
var SelectedText = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('click', function () {
                this.select();
            });
        }
    };
};

return SelectedText;
```

Comment: Share your code at least

Comment: Always prefer `ng-click` in favor of jQuery-style manual event adding.

Comment: Can you share all of the relevant HTML, assuming that there's HTML for your modal dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following directive will solve your problem:

```
app.directive("selectImmediately", function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, iElement) {
      $timeout(function() { // Using timeout to let template to be appended to DOM prior to select action.
        iElement[0].select()
     });
    }
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
<input ng-model="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="share" select-immediately >
```

Full example in plnkr can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lck506PJEiHOjq5DtnTm?p=preview). You can use this directive anywhere.

Comment: This answers the question - select text ON LOAD - not on click.